# Swift HttpSession decode arrays

Tags: swift, xcode, httpsession

I have a code to send post requests to a **NestJS** api. It works, but there's a request that returns the following json: (Multiplied the entrires to help understand the context)

```
[
    {
        "friendshipid": "64ad04f03e3afbddb87f2c82",
        "userid": "64ad04c53e3afbddb87f2c26",
        "username": "Alms2",
        "pfp": "http://localhost:3000/CDN//pfp/default.png"
    },
    {
        "friendshipid": "64ad04f03e3afbddb87f2c82",
        "userid": "64ad04c53e3afbddb87f2c26",
        "username": "Alms2",
        "pfp": "http://localhost:3000/CDN//pfp/default.png"
    }
]
```

How can i recognise it in my code? Thanks!

**HttpPOST.swift**

```
import Foundation
func apiCall<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, body: [String:AnyHashable]) async throws -> T {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.71:3000/\(urlString)") else { throw URLError(.badURL) }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    // method, body, headers
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
    
    // make rqs
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}

struct IsLoggedIn: Decodable {
    var loggedin: Bool
}

struct UserData: Decodable {
    var username: String;
    var userid: String;
    var pfp: String;
}

struct Friends: Decodable {
 // how to recognise???
}
```

Comment: Actually, you can't with this code base, it's an array. Try something like JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)

Comment: @son T can be declared to be an array so that part is fine. `let users: [UserData] = try await apiCall(urlString: x, body: y)` will work

Comment: What exactly are you asking about, what isn’t working in your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove:

```
struct Friends: Decodable {
 // how to recognise???
}
```

Change and add:

```
return try JSON Decoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
```

Also, you forgot to add **friendshipid**. And no need for ";" in the end.

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
  var username: String
  var userid: String
  var pfp: String
  var friendshipid: String
}
```

**T** means 1 element **{element}** and **[T]** means many elements **{element1, element2}**

Comment: [T] is not needed, see my comment above. And you don’t need to decode every field in a json dictionary.

Comment: Its working, but can you help me, how to store the response in a variable? I get a response like this: ```[Chatenium.FriendData(username: "Alms2", userid: "64ad04c53e3afbddb87f2c26", pfp: "http://localhost:3000/CDN//pfp/default.png", friendshipid: "64ad04f03e3afbddb87f2c82")]```

Comment: Looks like your response is an array with 1 element, so you can store this into a variable as `let user = response.first` or `let user = response[0]`